# Drag and drop between two lists

Tags: forms, javascript

When the user creates a blog entry, I want the user to be able to make some selection from a listbox. Therefore I want it to be a function where I drag and drop between one prefilled listbox (where the content will stay even when dragged) and an empty one. Pretty much like this example: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

How am I able to achieve this? Is there any module out there that can help me reach this goal?